# hide notification area progress bar in android when 100% is completed

Tags: android, notifications, hide, progress, invisible

I'm using [this tutorial](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/show-progressbar-in-notification-area-like-google-does-when-downloading-from-android)

to show a notification with a progress bar.

Everything works fine.

But I can not make the progress dissapear when the task is 100% done

How can I do this?
tx

Comment: cancel method is not working??????

Comment: cancel works but hides everything, I just want to have progress bar gone

Comment: Call the progressbar and use visibility GONE after 100% completion

Comment: But I don't know how to do that. everything I tried or does not work or gives me nullpointer exception

Answer (score 29):

Here it is:

```
Notification.setProgress(0, 0, false);
```

Where the first param stands for min and the second param stands for the maximum value.
Don’t forget to call:

```
Notification.notify(id, NotificationManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a "solution" that works.

Just call a new RemoteView with no progress bar on it's layout when the task is done

In the tutorial I use I have this progress.xml called:

```
            notification.contentView 
= new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.progress);
```

when the task is 100% done call:

```
            notification.contentView = 
new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.done);
```

so layout done.xml replaces progress.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 notificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: no that's not it. that hides everything not just only progress bar

Comment: implement a second progressbar in your laout and make it invisible then you just have to call :"notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progress2, 100, progress, false);" progress2 stands for the id of your second progressbar

Comment: I've got a solution. Don't have to implement a second progressbar you have to implement a full new layout

Answer (score 0):

To remove a `ProgressBar` from `RemoteView` use the following code :-

```
 remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progressBar, View.INVISIBLE);
```

You can also use `View.GONE` but that will make android to fill empty space.

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
 ProgressBar.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: it gives me nullpointer exception. first I have to get progress bar from remoteview. And I don't know how to do that